# Access a cell's value in other cell props (React-Table V7)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Is it possible to access the value of the cell in cell properties OTHER than "Cell"?

I'm trying to add dynamic classes to my cells based on the values within them (highlighting them in red or yellow, depending on the data), but I'm unsure of how to actually get the value in that prop.

Example of one of the objects in my columns array:

```
       {
            Header: 'Threshold',
            accessor: 'threshold',
            className: ((cellValue) => { if (cellValue>= 10){return 'bgRed'} else if (cellValue>= 5){ return 'bgYellow' } })(),
            Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => {
                return ( <div>{value}</div> )
            },
        }
```

Obviously, "cellValue" doesn't work, but that's where I'm hoping to be able to access the actual value from the accessor.

Is there any way to do this using React-Table V7?

My react-table setup looks like this:

```
           <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>                    
                {page.map((row, i) => {
                    prepareRow(row)
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps(getRowProps(row))}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return <td {...cell.getCellProps({ className: cell.column.className })}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
```